# How can I make grow an HTML container when it parent grows?

Tags: html, css, web, nav

I have a side nav that has to grow when its parent grows. Also I have a footer that has to be at the bottom of all the page.

Heres the CSS code:

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-color: #bababa;
    width: 100%;
}

main{  //the nav and main page container, not the footer
    position: relative;
}

#navIzquierda{ //the nav
    width: 20%;
    min-height: 90vh;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #d4d4d4;
}
```

thank you!
[image]

Comment: `width: 100%;` and `height: 100%;` will make a child consume all the parents width and height. Alternativly you have `flexbox` and `flex-grow`. I'm aware that many universities liek to teach outdated techniques for email templating, however, outside of email templates, `float`should not be used for styling purpose. Its a mis-used "hack" in that context.

Comment: espacially `body { float: left; }` makes no sense at all.